# Why does VSCode send a system notification when opening a file dialog?

Tags: 22.04, notification, visual-studio-code

When I create a new file in vscode and then hit ctrl+s to save the untitled file, instead of opening the file explorer window directly, it instead sends a system notification that says...

"Visual Studio Code: "Save As" is ready".

I then have to grab my mouse and click the notification to focus the file explorer.

How can I fix/disable this behaviour?

Comment: Same behavior for me on `22.04 Jammy` with `VSCode 1.69.2`.

Comment: Similar behavior using `latest/stable` **snap** versions of VSCode on 22.04: The system notification triggers as you describe, but the "Save As ..." dialog also opens *behind* the current VSC Workspace window. The "Save As ..." dialog sometimes opens on another Ubuntu Workspace. 

default **snap** source offers no alternate channels to `latest/stable` for VSCode. if the electron issue from Feb '22 @steinmn notes is resolved soon, I'll revisit moving back to non-snap versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently a known (and unfortunately currently unresolved) bug in the electron version vscode has upgraded to, see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/32857 and/or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146422

Answer (score 2):

Before Electron fixes the underlying issue that @steinmn references, you can work around it by installing [GrandTheftFocus](https://github.com/zalckos/GrandTheftFocus)