# How can I make VSCode's "**Save As**" dialog open in focus and on top of all other windows?

Tags: 22.04, visual-studio-code, electron

Currently, saving new files from VSCode to any VSCode Workspace triggers a system notification -- '"Save As" is ready' -- and opens VSCode's "**Save As**" dialog behind current windows. I want "**Save As**" dialogs to open in focus and on top of all other windows.

[image]

This "Save As ..." dialog sometimes opens on another Ubuntu Workspace. I posted [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413874/why-does-vscode-send-a-system-notification-when-opening-a-file-dialog#comment2506819_1413874),  researched [this issue with `electron`](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/32857), and have other electron apps running successfully without this issue.

Many thanks for your time and attention. I'm happy to provide more clarity and detail.

I prefer to run VSC **snap**. I've run other non-snap VSC versions on this same machine and changing wreaks havoc with extensions and **Settings Sync**. Default **snap** source offers no alternate channels to `latest/stable` for VSCode. Passing explicit electron versions to VSC at startup is a fine solution and I appreciate guidance making that so.

###### I'm reviewing these for applicability to my situation

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831882/configure-vs-code-to-debug-electron-in-ubuntu
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441950/warning-sandbox-is-not-in-the-list-of-known-options-but-still-passed-to-elec/68380418#68380418
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009611/can-visual-studio-code-be-configured-to-launch-electron/39430029#39430029

Comment: Updates: I've installed electron globally and added that global path `~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.1/bin/electron` to **launch.json** for multiple Workspaces. This has not yet consistently addressed my issues with Save As dialog focus. I'm working to add the same electron info to `~/.vscode/argv.json` for a more global scope, but have not yet had success.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5410/grand-theft-focus/) that will remove the "****** is ready" notification and instead focus on the window that sent the notification. That will also include Vscode's "**Save As**".